# Export const arrow function or basic function?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

Which is better to do: export a `const` arrow function, like so:

```
export const foo = () => 'bar'
```

or export a regular function, like so:

```
export function baz() {
  return 'bar';
}
```

They compile like so:

```
exports.baz = baz;
function baz() {
  return 'bar';
}
var foo = exports.foo = function foo() {
  return 'bar';
};
```

It looks like using the const/arrow function combination declares an extra variable (`foo`), which seems to be an unnecessary extra step over the simple function declaration.

Comment: This is ECMAScript 6 being compiled into ECMAScript 5, right?

Comment: The question supposes that ES6 code is transpiled to ES5 with Babel, this may not be true.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for not being clear. The ES6 is being transpiled into ES5 via Babel.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The differences are minuscule. Both declare a variable.

- A `const` variable is constant also within your module, while a function declaration theoretically could be overwritten from inside the module
- An arrow function is [a function expression, not a function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572), and the assignment can lead to problems for circular dependencies
- An arrow function cannot [be a constructor or use a dynamic `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572)
- An arrow function is a few characters shorter if you use a concise body and a few characters longer if you use a block body.
- A function declaration better expresses intention to be callable. The arrow function stored in a `const` can get lost among other `const`s.

Comment: So architecturally speaking, as long as the function does not need a constructor or `this`, a `const` variable should be fine? Can you elaborate on point number 2, re: circular dependencies?

Comment: @MarosIvanco re your edit: a function declaration does not create a constant. Module exports are immutable from the outside only.

Comment: Other considerations can be made, such as some mocking libraries can't support testing if arrow functions are called, but they can if regular functions are used. For example, typemoq: `For static mocks, TypeMoq is able to verify any inner calls inside regular functions but not inside lambda ones. E.g.:`

Comment: @ps2goat That appears to be a shortcoming of the `TypeMoq` library and of class fields, less of arrow functions. Similar to "not being able to reassign a function expression" when you use `const`.